# Neo4j cypher query - How to return path nodes but not include the nodes with identical specific properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I’m trying to MATCH nodes from the Neo4j database and filter the result I get from the path value with no success.

I’m currently using a query like this:

```
MATCH path = (x:x)-[y:y]->(f:f) return DISTINCT nodes(path)
```

and the result I get is:

> [{“property1”:“prop1"}, {“property2”:“b”}, {“property3”:“c”}]
>
> [{“property1”:“prop2"}, {“property2”:“b”}, {“property3”:“c”}]
>
> [{“property1”:“prop3"}, {“property2”:“b”}, {“property3”:“c”}]

but I want the returning result to be distinct  by a pair of node properties (property2 and property3)

so the result should be only one of the three:

> [{“property1”:“prop1"}, {“property2”:“b”}, {“property3”:“c”}]

I don’t mind what is the value I get in “property1”, it can be any of the three.

is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` to generate a list of all the paths that share each distinct pair of `property2/property3` values, and assigns the first path from each list to the `path` variable. Therefore, the returned `path` values will all have a distinct pair of `property2/property3` values.

```
MATCH p = (:x)-[y:y]->(f:f)
WITH y.property2 AS p2, f.property3 AS p3, COLLECT(p)[0] AS path
RETURN path
```

Comment: Hi thank you! it works, but did not quite understand how exactly,
 what do you mean by " list of all the paths that share each distinct pair",  what do I get in the COLLECT(p)[1] or the next list value?
 and if I add more properties in the "with" statement , how it going to work?

thanks